# compute Hessians w.r.t higher rank variable not work neither by tf.hessians() nor tf.gradients()

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

When we need to calculate double gradient or Hessian, in tensorflow, we may use `tf.hessians(F(x),x)`, or use `tf.gradient(tf.gradients(F(x),x)[0], x)[0]`. However, when `x` is not rank one, I was told the following error when use `tf.hessians()`.

> ValueError: Cannot compute Hessian because element 0 of xs does not
>   have rank one..  Tensor model_inputs/action:0 must have rank 1.
>   Received rank 2, shape (?, 1)

in following code:

```
with tf.name_scope("1st scope"):
      self.states = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, self.state_dim), name="states")
      self.action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, self.action_dim), name="action")

with tf.name_scope("2nd scope"):
  with tf.variable_scope("3rd scope"):
    self.policy_outputs = self.policy_network(self.states)
    # use tf.gradients twice
    self.actor_action_gradients = tf.gradients(self.policy_outputs, self.action)[0]
    self.actor_action_hessian = tf.gradients(self.actor_action_gradients, self.action)[0]
    # or use tf.hessians 
    self.actor_action_hessian = tf.hessian(self.policy_outputs, self.action)
```

When using `tf.gradients()`, also causes an error:

> in create_variables self.actor_action_hessian =
>   tf.gradients(self.actor_action_gradients, self.action)[0]
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'

How can I fix this, does neither `tf.gradients()` nor `tf.hessians()` can be used in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is fine, error is somewhere else, namely your graph is not connected.

```
self.actor_action_gradients = tf.gradients(self.policy_outputs, self.action)[0]
self.actor_action_hessian = tf.gradients(self.actor_action_gradients, self.action)[0]
```

errror is thrown in second line because self.actor_action_gradients is None, and so you can't compute its gradient. Nothing in your code suggests that self.policy_outputs depends on self.action (and it shouldn't, since its action that depends on policy, not policy on action).

Once you fix this you will notice, that "hessian" is not really a hessian but a vector, to form a proper hessian of f wrt. x you have to iterate over all values returned by tf.gradients, and compute tf.gradients of each one independently. This is a known limitation in TF, and no simpler way is available right now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your information is very helpful.  So currently the return of `tf.hessians()` is the same as applying  `tf.gradients()` twice?